# Find text and replace with hyperlink

Tags: regex, vba, replace, outlook

I am trying to replace text in the body with pattern ASA####@@ to ASA####@@(hyperlink)

I have code which works if there is only one pattern in the body.

But if I have many patterns like

ASA3422df
ASA2389ds
ASA1265sa

the entire body gets replaced to

ASAhuyi65

My code is here.

```vb
Dim strID As String
Dim Body As String
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim temp As String
Dim RegExpReplace As String
Dim RegX As Object
strID = MyMail.EntryID

Set objMail = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(strID)
Body = objMail.HTMLBody
Body = Body + "Test"
objMail.HTMLBody = Body

Set RegX = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With RegX
.Pattern = "ASA[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-z][a-z]"
.Global = True
.IgnoreCase = Not MatchCase
End With
'RegExpReplace = RegX.Replace(Body, "http://www.code.com/" + RegX.Pattern + "/ABCD")

'if the replacement is longer than the search string, future .FirstIndexes will be off
Offset = 0
'Set matches = RegX.Execute(Body)

For Each m In RegX.Execute(Body)
    RegExReplace = "<a href=""http://www.code.com/" & m.Value & """>" & m.Value & "</a>"
Next

Set RegX = Nothing
objMail.HTMLBody = RegExReplace
objMail.Save
Set objMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you were on the right track originally with that commented-out line. With the `Replace` method don't need to loop over matches (that's what the `Global` flag is for), and can use backreferences like `$1`, `$2`, etc. as placeholders for matching substrings. As with most languages, there's [a dedicated page on Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html) for VBScript.

The following with do what you're looking for:

```
body = "Blah blah ASA3422df ASA2389ds ASA1265sa"
body = RegX.Replace(body, "<a href='http://www.code.com/$1'>$1</a>")
Debug.Print body 
'-> Blah blah <a href='http://www.code.com/ASA3422df'>ASA3422df</a> <a href='http://www.code.com/ASA2389ds'>ASA2389ds</a> <a href='http://www.code.com/ASA1265sa'>ASA1265sa</a>
```

This replaces the matches (and *only* the matches) with a link, and leaves everything else untouched.

Comment: Just tested this; it returns `Blah blah <a href='http://www.code.com/$1'>$1</a>` etc., i.e. not what you report. However, `Body = RegX.Replace(Body, "<a href='http://www.code.com/$&'>$&</a>")` correctly returns `Blah blah <a href='http://www.code.com/ASA3422df'>ASA3422df</a>` etc.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. I pasted the result straight from my VBE window, but I did use Excel and not Outlook. Perhaps there's a difference?

Comment: I'm using Excel as well. 2003. Go figure!!

Comment: Very odd indeed. Works on both 2003 and 2007 on my XP machine. I guess these kinds of quirks can happen sometimes with external libraries, which is good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Over at codedawn, there is a fantastic add-in for Excel that gives you the same UI search and replace that you know and love, but for regular expressions.
http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php

While this doesn't exactly help answer your question, it's useful for trying out regular expressions one after another without altering data or code.