# Detecting format of body in Outlook 2007 in VB

Tags: vba, outlook, format

I am trying to detect the format of the body of an email message in outlook 2007 using a macro.

> if body is plain text
>
> convert to HTML
>
> perform the operation
>
> Display as HTML with Font Consolas
>   and size as 10.5
>
> else if body is in HTML
>
> ```
> perform the operation and display it as HTML itself
> ```

I know to change the format of the body by using

```
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
strID = MyMail.EntryID
Set objMail = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(strID)
objMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML ' changes to HTML/Richtext/plaintext
```

there is also a detailed documentation available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx

This does not tell about detecting format of item body in outlook. So how will I do the detection of format for an item body in email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how to detect and change the body format:

```
If objMail.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain Then
    objMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Jean, I am not able to accept your answer as I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Sure, you're able! Click on the checkmark to the left of it. You've done so before [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420859/find-and-replace-text-using-regexp-in-vb) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399031/replace-specific-ids-in-body-with-specific-hyperlinks).

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just test the value of objMail.BodyFormat?

```
olFormatHTML = 2
olFormatPlain = 1
olFormatRichText = 3
olFormatUnspecified = 0
```

Comment: these constants are available in enumeration: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864792.aspx